# System.DllNotFoundException from C# when calling from VB6 Code in the IDE

Tags: c#, dll, vb6, pinvoke

This question is specific to **calling native code via managed code from the VB6 IDE / debugger**. (Maybe it would apply to debugging from other languages i.e. Delphi, etc. but I'm not sure.)

---

We are calling C# DLLs via COM from VB6. The C# DLL relies on calling native code in compiled DLLs via p/invoke.

When running *in the VB6 IDE* the call into the C# code results in this exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'name_of_library': 
The specified module could not be found.
```

However if we run the VB6 code compiled this error does not occur. All the native code DLLs are located alongside the compiled C# DLLs. The VB6 code produces the EXE for the application.

Why does this error occur?

Comment: I've found a workaround which I posted below; but I'm not sure if that is the only solution or the best one.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. This issue is specific to interfacing to C# within the VB6 IDE. Maybe it could apply to other IDEs too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the location of the native code DLLs.

When everything including the EXE is compiled then colocating all the DLLs and the EXE satisfies the search order that Windows uses to find DLLs.

But when running in the VB6 IDE, it is apparently **the location of the IDE itself** which determines the EXE location used in the DLL search.

i.e., in my case I had to locate the native code DLLs in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98`

When I did that, the error was resolved. This is awkward, but workable.

Comment: Terrible idea, don't modify that folder, find a better solution to your problem

Comment: I didn't say this was a "good idea". But it does explain the problem. An alternative (as stated in the question) was to compile the VB6 code, but then you obviously lose the ability to debug interactively. VB6 is a dinosaur and I can accept that some level of hacking may be necessary nowadays to keep it running.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution.  When you run the basic code in the IDE then it is always interpreted.  So there is no executable file that the operating system can use to find other DLLs.  Except one, vb6.exe.  You could technically monkey with the PATH environment variable I guess, not exactly that superior.  Getting it to execute the exact way it will execute on the user's machine just isn't an option.

Comment: You might need to set the "Current Directory" either within your VB6 code (the ChDir function) or in whatever shortcut you use to launch VB6. But if your code depends on what the current directory is, you should probably fix that instead.

Comment: @HansPassant is correct.  The referenced dlls simply need to be in the vb6.exe folder. You can automate this process (at least when you are recompiling the C# project) by adding into your Visual Studio C# project a post build event to copy the dll to the vb6.exe folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98 on 64bit Windows), as well as taking any other necessary steps such as registering, configuring, etc.

Comment: Don't agree at all. Use the PATH to locate your libraries.

Comment: I agree 100% with @David Heffernan as you will be able to trap errors (same as to what is happening to OP), search for correct files before executing the C# read process etc. All users systems and folders differ and to hard code the location will almost certainly end in error upon error.